# Does upvoting very downvoted questions have any impact on your account?

Tags: support, voting

Does the automated system consider this case in any sense? My guess is "no" since I haven't found any information about this anywhere yet.

(I'm asking because I personally upvote downvoted questions quite often and wanted to know)

As people ask why I upvote those questions and maybe why I'm asking this, I'll try to clarify it:

I mainly upvote edited questions that have good answers with useful information (and many upvotes) and were heavily downvoted in an early stage and never had the upvotes back again.

Those kinds of questions are probably initially poorly written by new users and thus get the downvotes, but eventually they get good pieces of information through answers that are very useful for other similar new users. That way, the answer gets lots of upvotes while the question still does not get upvotes even if it's already fully corrected and never shows up again as valuable for the community.

So that's why I was wondering if there was a technical reason for this apart from the probable fear that a new user or even any other user has to contradict the community.

Comment: Why do you "up vote down voted questions quite often"? Pity upvotes or some other reason?

Comment: I mostly up vote questions that have been edited and have become very correct that also have very useful and accepted answers that have been very up voted and are still down voted (the question not the answer). Anyway i was just asking for the feature.

Comment: Do you mean these upvotes as a _'heads up'_, or do you want to _take heart_ for the OP? That's certainly a misunderstanding, and a wrong action. Also, add some samples to your question please.

Comment: 9 upvoted questions is "quite often"?

Comment: Compared to my total activity, yes, it's quite often ^^

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Upvoting a heavily downvoted question is not seen as a voting abuse in itself. It won't be held against you and will not lead to repercussions. If you find that a negatively scoring post actually is quite good (or has become quite good), you are free to vote as you see fit.

However, do keep in mind that it's quality we're after. If you just feel sorry for a user, please don't provide them with pity upvotes. (This might of course not apply to you) At most help them improve their content so they deserve the upvote.